# Calling Applet method returning map from java script

Tags: java, javascript, spring, applet

I am writing an Java Spring aaplication in which i have one Applet.
Basically i have to call the Applet method that returns MAP();. I can't edit applet method so it is necessary to handle this returned map value from the javascript only.

So how can i call java applet method that returns MAP and binding it's result to spring  ....  tag.

Comment: Why not just get that method in your spring app.

Comment: This applet basically provides gethostname() and getprinterlist() methods. so i want printers list of the client not of server. When i am using it in sprnig controller then it gives me list of server's printer

Comment: Can you atleast clear out where are you using spring, is it to build a web app or you will run it on client side as stand alone app.

Comment: So application is totally build up in Spring MVC. This application will be hosted on the server and multiple users can access the application. So when any user access the application, then app should list all the printers configured in client machine to take a printout.

Comment: In that case you have no way to call a method of applet that executes on client side. You can do the other way around. You can scan for a list of printers from applet, and can push it to server, where spring can utilize from there.